# How can I make a conditional IF statement in order to call a reformatting module

Tags: vba, excel

I have a script that gathers an array based on a value in my raw data, but some of the rows in that array will need to be grey font and italicized.

How would I do something like:

```
Dim strAction As String

Dim ActionRow As Long

Dim colAction As Long
colAction = 3

For ActionRow = 2 to ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count

if ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(ActionRow, 3).Value = "No Action" Then

Call Row_Reformat

End If

Next
```

Paraphrasing, on whatever current new sheet (actual sheet name could be Sheet 54, so I'll need it to reference only current sheet) I'm on, if a row in column C has value = "No Action" then Call a module I use to reformat that entire row as Italicized and grey font

EDIT:

I tried the following and it works when I put:

```
2 to 10' To Wb.Worksheet("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count
```

But this doesn't work:

```
For ActionRow = 2 To Wb.Worksheet("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count
                        If .Cells(ActionRow, 3).Value = "No Action" Then
                            .Range("A" & ActionRow & ":AB" & ActionRow).Font.Italic = True
                            .Range("A" & ActionRow & ":AB" & ActionRow).Font.Color = 10921638
                        End If
                    Next ActionRow
```

Comment: You need to pass a qualified range to your sub `Row_Reformat`. If you are just changing the color, you don't really need a 2nd sub. Just do it here. Just replace the `Call` with 2 lines stating the format

Comment: What would I implement to specify entirerow of the cells where "No Action" comes up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My approach would be to format the rows right then and there without a second sub *if* these are the only actions you are taking. My preference is to only pass parameters to other subs when the action is large in scope. This is how I would go about doing this in one sub.

---

### Option 1

```
Sub Tester()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim i As Long

For i = 2 To ws.Range("C" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If ws.Range("C" & i) = "No Action" Then
        ws.Range("C" & i).EntireRow.Font.Italic = True
        ws.Range("C" & i).EntireRow.Interior.Color = "INSERT COLER NUMBER HERE"
    Else
        'Do what you want if the value is NOT "No Action"
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

---

### Option 2

If your preference is to pass your range to a new sub dedicated to handling the action statement of a range showing `No Action`,  you will need to implement something like this:

```
Sub LoopSub()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim i As Long

For i = 2 To ws.Range("C" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If ws.Range("C" & i) = "No Action" Then
        No_Action ws.Range("C" & i)
    Else
        'Do what you want if the value is NOT "No Action"
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

```
Sub No_Action(Target As Range)

With Target
    .EntireRow.Font.Italic = True
    .EntireRow.Interior.Color = "INSERT COLOR NUMBER HERE"
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Doesn't hurt to learn how to separate concerns into separate procedures, and how to pass parameters around. No program ever written "needs" multiple classes and scopes and whatnot - as long as it compiles, code can run perfectly fine with global scope and a single God procedure, but code is written for humans to read and maintain, not just for some runtime to execute. OP's idea of having a procedure responsible solely for formatting a single row is an excellent way of thinking, I respectfully disagree with shooting it down (upvoted anyway).

Comment: Well in my comment below the solution I addressed (*vaguely*) what steps were needed to pass this along to another sub. When to pass parameters, for the most part, seems to be a matter of personal preference. I tend to only do that when the action statements have large scope. If it is just 2 lines, I prefer to just handle it on the spot. I should probably rephrase my solution - my intention was not to *shoot down* the original idea. Just to offer a different persons perspective :) @MathieuGuindon

Comment: @MathieuGuindon solution updated to show both methods :)

Comment: @urdearboy

I had success with my EDIT: that I posted in my OP, but when I took out the comment and tried making it count to last row, it said object not supported